# How do I hide a redstone torch while placing a block to activate redstone in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to place a block to activate redstone but how will I hide the redstone torch?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking, perhaps with a screenshot of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want a place to look like just a regular wall or floor until you place a block in an exact spot?

Comment: I don't know what it will look like.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is something that is BUD activated. Here is one such example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3n9fUXPGrZA

Comment: How do you build a Block Update Detector?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want to activate or power a Redstone component such as a powered rail.  What I do to hide the torch is place it two blocks below the rail.  One block of stone above the torch, and the rail above that.

If you are looking for a BUD (block update detector) it depends on what you are trying to do.  There are a lot of different methods and some are version dependent.  Check the minecraft wiki for many examples and if you need help with one in particular, feel free to update your OP here so we can provide better assistance.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Block_update_detector

Comment: I wasn't looking for redstone components! I was looking for blocks like furnaces, crafting tables and wood!

Comment: Furnaces crafting tables and wood don't activate redstone nor are they activated by redstone, with the exception of a furnace if you have a redstone triggered hopper feeding it fuel.  So I'm still really not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: I said, blocks like furnaces, crafting tables and wood! I actually mean that it includes it! Note the LIKE in the comment.